# scanf() not taking input from console

Tags: c, scanf

```
#include<stdio.h> 

int main() {

    float a, b, r;
    char op;

    scanf("%f",&a);
    scanf("%c",&op);
    scanf("%f",&b);
    scanf("%f",&r);

    switch(op) {

        case '+':
            r = a + b;
            printf("%f", r);
        break;

        case '-':
            r = a - b;     
            printf("%f", r);     
        break;

        case '*':
            r = a * b;    
            printf("%f", r);     
        break;

        case '/':
            r = a / b;     
            printf("%f", r);     
        break;

        default:
            printf ("Nekaj ne delas prav");

    }

    return 0;

}
```

it is giving output

> "Nekaj ne delas prav"

and  not taking any input. instead of using 'scanf()'and why it directly gives default value as output instead of using switch statement.

Comment: You should use the preview feature to check your code is correctly inserted and readable. The preview is WYSIWYG so it's reliable

Comment: For some specific input, please provide the expected and actua output. And please *please* format your code so it's readable, you *have* heard of indentation?

Comment: What is your actual question? Please be (much) more specific than "it's not working".

Comment: I voted to close, because *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)*

Comment: also, take the time to format readably.

Comment: @MarcusMüller You should include the link to your "See:"

Comment: @Eregrith: good point; edited :)

Comment: output is "Nekaj ne delas prav",it is not taking input from scanf().

Comment: @Dikshant have you tried `printf("You entered char [%c]\n", op);` just by curiosity?

Comment: @Dikshant I'll bet anything that `scanf` reads input, but it's not the input you expect it to be. Please ***edit the question*** to show the actual input.

Comment: I think you all have read the problem and also punished me by down voting me.Now will you help me to find why this program is taking input istead of using scanf() and why it is giving drect default value as a output.

Comment: why are you reading `r` from `stdin`? It is the result variable.

Comment: We have not only told you what the most likely problem is and how to solve it, we have also told you how to improve the question (also see http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and you haven't done that. Neither have you acknowledged the solutions posted both as comments and as answers. Start by telling us the complete and actual input you enter to your program, then modify your code to see what [`scanf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) returns and tell us that as well.

Comment: It is not taking any input ,it is just giving "Nekaj ne delas prav" as output and then program terminates

Answer (score 4):

In your code, please change

```
scanf("%f",&a);
scanf("%c",&op);
scanf("%f",&b);
scanf("%f",&r);
```

to

```
scanf("%f",&a);
scanf(" %c",&op);  //notice here
scanf("%f",&b);
scanf("%f",&r);
```

Without the leading space before `%c`, the `\n` stoted by previous <kbd>ENTER</kbd> key press after previous input, will be read and considered as valid input for `%c` format specifier. So, the second `scanf()` will not *ask* for seperate user input and the flow will continue to the third `scanf()`.

The whitespace before `%c` will consume all leading whitespace like `char`s, including the `\n` stoted by previous <kbd>ENTER</kbd> key press and will consider only a non-whitespace input.

Note:

1. `%f` format specifier reads and *ignores* the leading `\n`, so in that case, you don't need to provide the leading space before `%f` explicitly.
2. The signature of `main()` is `int main(void)`.

Comment: I have already done that but still not working.

Comment: are you sure that it is not working? https://ideone.com/aHcrZk

Comment: @Dikshant what is your input? how you are providing the inputs?

Comment: "ya its not working,I am not able to provide input ,it just giving output as"Nekaj ne delas prav" and then program terminates.

Comment: @Dikshant That's strange !! How you are compiling your code and running your binary?

Comment: "I am using online compiler codepad.org"

Comment: @Dikshant that is because in codepad you don't have the option to provide the input. Try a better alternative, ideone.com. put your input in `stdin` field before running.

Comment: "I also use ideone.com on your recommendation but still same same output.,not able to take input.I am not getting where i am going wrong."

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75937/discussion-between-dikshant-and-sourav-ghosh).

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
scanf("%c", myNothing);
```

to:

```
scanf("%c", &myNothing);
```

Or better yet:

```
myNothing = getchar();
```

Also, make sure you have compiler warnings enabled.