# if statement producing wrong behaviour even after having correct targeted input value

Tags: c, scanf, nested-if

I'm trying to make a simple game to master the Nested If statement. I'm still new at C language and I only have a small in Java.

```
#define p printf
#define s scanf
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
    char p1,p2;
r:  p("Player 1 : ");
    s("%s",&p1);
    p("Player 2 : ");
    s("%s",&p2);
    if ((p1=='s') && (p2=='s')){
        p("It's a draw\n");
    }else if (p1=='r' && p2=='r'){
        p("It's a Draw\n");
    }else if (p1=='p' && p2=='p'){
        p("It's a Draw\n");
    }else if (p1=='s' && p2=='r'){
        p("Player 2 Wins\n");
    }else if (p1=='s' && p2=='p'){
        p("Player 1 Wins\n");
    }else if (p1=='r' && p2=='s'){
        p("Player 1 Wins\n");
    }else if (p1=='r' && p2=='p'){
        p("Player 2 Wins\n");
    }else if (p1=='p' && p2=='s'){
        p("Player 1 Wins\n");
    }else if (p1=='p' && p2=='r'){
        p("Player 1 Wins\n");
    }
    goto r;
}
```

Okay, so I'll go over the problems here :

1. Somehow I can't get the `&&` operator to work here. Everytime I enter something for `p1` and `p2` the statement inside the `if` doesn't work.
2. Should I change my variable type to something else? Or should I change my `scanf` to something else?
3. I want to try and use the `switch` statement here but I haven't looked it up on how to use it yet.

Comment: Instead of the label & `goto`, use a `while` instead.

Comment: Don't use `#define p printf`. This bad practice because is make your code less readable.

Comment: I'd suggest rewriting this without the long chain of if-else statements. Try declaring constants named R, S and P, assigning numeric values to them and then comparing those values. I'll leave it as an exercise to you to figure out how you'll make that comparison.

Answer (score 1):

In your code

```
 s("%s",&p1);
 ....
 s("%s",&p2);
```

are wrong and invokes undefined behaviour. `p1` and `p2` are of type `char` and you should be using `%c` format specifier to intake the values.

Using `p1` and `p2` as the arguments of `%s` makes the attempt to write past the allocated memory and invokes  [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Comment: I tried to use `%c` but when I enter a value for `p1` it skips the `scanf` for `p2` and ends the program.

Comment: @IDon'tKnowYou Yes, put a space before the `%c`, like `scanf(" %c", &p2)` which will _skip_ the previously pressed ENTER key,.

Comment: Dear Downvoter, care to add a comment about the downvote?

Comment: @IDon'tKnowYou For more related info you can check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29796838/2173917).

Comment: Thank you for the info about the space before the `%c`! I finally managed to make the program work without a problem.

Comment: @IDon'tKnowYou Happy to help!! but somehow I _managed_ to get the downvote for some reason I'm unable to understand. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
 s("%s",&p1);

 s("%s",&p2);
```

Specifer should be `%c`as `p1` and `p2` are `char`. Thus wrong argument invokes UB.

Comment: @SouravGhosh Yes that will be appropriate .Thanks !!

Comment: I used `%c` first when I made it. As I have said in the other answer, it skips the `p2` so I changed it to `%s`. And could you take a look at my conditions if I have any mistakes in it?

Comment: @IDon'tKnowYou  `s("  %c",&p1);`  leave space before `%c` in both `scanf`  in next time first `scanf` will fail.